# What is the SQL query for creating a new database in Oracle 10G Express?

Tags: sql

What is the SQL query for creating a new database in Oracle 10G Express?

Comment: If you want it very fast, why don't you Google it?

Comment: Patience.  Asking for people to answer your question "very fast" will almost guarantee nobody will want to help you.  If you really want something that fast, you can find the information in documentation faster than relying on someone to point you to it.

Comment: The only thing worse than "give me the code" is "give me the code NOW!"

Comment: You should have spelled it "pleaze".  That always getz more attention.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name options
```

List of other commands is [here](http://ss64.com/ora/)

I googled that and it took 2 mins, and I know nothing about DBs!!!!!

Comment: +1 Good point - it took 8 minutes from question to answer on SO. For such common questions, searching would be the logical zeroth step (before asking here).

Comment: @Piskvor: <shocked look!>  What - people are supposed to do something hard like *Google for an answer*?!?!?  Whatever is the world coming to??!!  Geez - before you know it we'll be expected to go get *big heavy books* off of *shelves* and we'll have to *go through them page by page* to find answers!!!!  Horrors!!!!!  <signed> Bob, who is old enough to remember when...

Comment: hmm someone's not reading [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) ;)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: Yeah, it was more of a comment on "i wnat very fast". btw, do you get bulk rates on your punctuation? ;o)

Comment: @Conrad Frix - sorry I am new to this site, I opened an account ages ago but only recently started as an active user. I wasn't aware of such a blog and I will read it now and be more careful in future. Apologies. I guess I am not helping anyone by answering such stupid questions! I will be more careful in future.

Comment: @Digger sorry my apologies I was just trying to come up with a clever way of pointing to the blog entry and I ended up coming off wrong footed. Also while Jeff does carry a lot of weight in the SO community you shouldn't take his blog as gospel. If you feel like answering a question I say go ahead.

Comment: @Conrad Frix - thanks, if I am going to use the site I guess reading the blog would be helpful too!

Comment: @Piskvor: the alphabet salesman had a special on exclamation points and question marks, and - OMG!!! - there was this *italicized font* that I just **HAD** to have.  :-)